# String between a line

Tags: vbscript

By some google resources I could write a program to extract the string between two specific strings. I could not print value or store the value into a variable using regular expressions. Here is my code.

```
prgName = InStr(vText, "Program")
sub_prgName = Mid(vText, prgName, 100)
MsgBox sub_prgName, vbInformation
Dim RegEx: Set RegEx = New RegExp
RegEx.IgnoreCase = True
RegEx.Pattern = "Program(.*)?Variant"
Set RegEx = RegEx.Execute(prgName)
MsgBox RegEx.Value, vbInformation
```

I want to get the string b/w Program and Variant. When try to see the output it says

> Run time error 438, object doesn't support this property.

This is the value that I want to parse using RegEx:

```
Program

sqlplus $SOPS_MIPO_USER/$SOPS_MIPO_PASSWORD@$DB_SID @mipo_pruning.sql

Variant
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfy6y4h1%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). The `Execute` method returns a [`Matches` collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx0sf6z1%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), so you need to iterate over that collection to get the desired result (in your case the first [submatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y27d2s18%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)).

```
For Each m In RegEx.Execute(prgName)
  MsgBox m.SubMatches(0), vbInformation
Next
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> s = "Program sqlplus $SOPS_MIPO_USER/$SOPS_MIPO_PASSWORD@$DB_SID @mipo_pruning.sql Variant N/A"
>>> Set re = New RegExp
>>> re.Pattern = "Program(.*)?Variant"
>>> re.IgnoreCase = True
>>> For Each m In re.Execute(s) : WScript.Echo m.SubMatches(0) : Next
 sqlplus $SOPS_MIPO_USER/$SOPS_MIPO_PASSWORD@$DB_SID @mipo_pruning.sql
```

Theoretically you could also do this without the loop:

```
Set m = RegEx.Execute(prgName)(0)
MsgBox m.SubMatches(0), vbInformation
```

However, `RegEx.Execute(prgName)(0)` would raise an error if the regular expression didn't find a match, so evaluating the results in a loop is the safer approach.

I'd remove the `?` in your regular expression, though, because it'll make the group optional, so you're not guaranteed to have a `SubMatches(0)` item. Simply use `Program(.*)Variant` instead. If there's no text between "Program" and "Variant" you'll get a zero-length string as the first submatch. Or you could put it inside the parentheses right after the asterisk (`Program(.*?)Variant`) to make the match non-greedy (shortest match instead of longest match).

If your input string contains newlines you need to use `[\s\S]` instead of `.`, because the dot in regular expressions matches any character *except newlines*.

Demonstration:

```
>>> s = "Program" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
& "sqlplus $SOPS_MIPO_USER/$SOPS_MIPO_PASSWORD@$DB_SID @mipo_pruning.sql" _
& vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Variant"
>>> WScript.Echo s
Program

sqlplus $SOPS_MIPO_USER/$SOPS_MIPO_PASSWORD@$DB_SID @mipo_pruning.sql

Variant
>>> Set re = New RegExp
>>> re.Pattern = "Program(.*)?Variant"
>>> re.IgnoreCase = True
>>> For Each m In re.Execute(s) : WScript.Echo m.SubMatches(0) : Next
>>> re.Pattern = "Program([\s\S]*)?Variant"
>>> For Each m In re.Execute(s) : WScript.Echo m.SubMatches(0) : Next


sqlplus $SOPS_MIPO_USER/$SOPS_MIPO_PASSWORD@$DB_SID @mipo_pruning.sql
```

---

As a side note, you shouldn't replace your regular expression object with the result of the `Execute` method.

```
Set RegEx = RegEx.Execute(prgName)    '<-- NEVER do this!
```

Re-using variables is a no-no, so don't do it.

Comment: @Wiechers, I have gone through the documentation, but could not figure out how could I save the result to a variable which I have to export to excel. There will be only one result in the collection always. I could not get the output when I used SubMatches.

Comment: @venkat The above should do what you want. If it doesn't: show the input string you're trying to process with the regular expression.

Comment: Program sqlplus $SOPS_MIPO_USER/$SOPS_MIPO_PASSWORD@$DB_SID @mipo_pruning.sql
Variant N/A
The above is the input string. I want the string b/w "program" and "Variant"

Comment: @Wiechers, when used the above code Set m = RegEx.Execute(prgName)(0) ... I got runtime error 5 at this line.

Comment: @venkat Does your input string perhaps contain linebreaks?

Comment: @Wiechers, it is a html table data reading from an outlook mail.

Comment: SAP System (or Legacy) PB5
SAP Client 200
Redwood Job ID  173497874
SAP Job ID (or Legacy)  173056100
REDWOOD Job Name B5_D_BI_HN_TMS_1_LOAD_TESTIN_CST
SAP Job Name N/A
Description 
Program sqlplus $SOPS_MIPO_USER/$SOPS_MIPO_PASSWORD@$DB_SID @mipo_pruning.sql
Variant N/A
SAP User ID  N/A
Date & Time Mon, 22 Jun 2015, 02:06:21 AM - Central Daylight Time

Comment: <tr>
<td width="0" style="width:.3pt;background:white;padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-line-height-alt:0pt"><span class="estilo41">Redwood Job ID
</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
<td width="0" style="width:.3pt;background:#CACAFF;padding:.75pt .75pt .75pt .75pt">
<p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-line-height-alt:0pt"><span class="estilo41">173497874</span><o:p></o:p></p>
</td>
</tr>  .... this is how the source of the mail looks like.. I mean the source of body of the email.

Comment: Program

sqlplus $SOPS_MIPO_USER/$SOPS_MIPO_PASSWORD@$DB_SID @mipo_pruning.sql

Comment: updated the question. apologies for any inconvenience.

Comment: @venkat So, basically, yes, your string contains linebreaks. You need to replace `.` with `[\s\S]` in your regular expression, because `.` doesn't match newline characters. I already updated my answer with this information 3 hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

`.Execute` returns a **collection** of Match objects. This collection has a .Count but no .Value property. You can use `MsgBox RegEx(0).Value` to get the .Value of the first match.

Evidence:

```
>> sInp = "XXXProgramYYYVariantZZZ"
>> Set r = New RegExp
>> r.Pattern = "Program(.*?)Variant"
>> WScript.Echo r.Execute(sInp)(0).Value
>> WScript.Echo r.Execute(sInp)(0).SubMatches(0)
>>
ProgramYYYVariant
YYY
```

You should publish your input(s) and expected result(s).

Comment: Thanks Horner, the result is same. Here are my inputs and expected results. Input:  Program sqlplus $SOPS_MIPO_USER/$SOPS_MIPO_PASSWORD@$DB_SID @mipo_pruning.sql
Variant N/A.   I want to get the string between Program and Variant

Comment: @Horner, but I was unable to print the result in the outlook editor. Am I missing something like declarations. I neither see error nor result.